# What is the largest timestamp parseable with DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME?

Tags: java-time

I thought that I could use `Instant.MAX` to represent the maximum timestamp possible but

```
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse(Instant.MAX.toString());
```

raises an exception:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): 1000000000
```

I understand that for the specific case of `Instant.MAX` I could use:

```java
Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(Instant.MAX.toString()))
```

but I do really need to use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` and I would rather use a constant that represent the maximum timestamp for that parser.

I have two questions really

- Is there some **stardard** constant that I can use to represent the largest timestamp that is still parseable by `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`
- What is the rationale for `Instant.MAX` being outside the valid range of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` the maximum and minimum timestamps are `OffsetDateTime.MAX` and `OffsetDateTime.MIN`.

```
OffsetDateTime.MAX.toString() // +999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999-18:00
OffsetDateTime.MIN.toString() // -999999999-01-01T00:00+18:00
```

```java
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;


Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse(OffsetDateTime.MAX.toString()));
```